# How to use TVF mapped to C# function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

In EF CORE 5 there is a **[way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-8/#table-valued-functions)** to map a TVF to function in C#. I did my best on following the guide.

TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GenerateActiveMonthsRange
(   
    @StartDate DATETIME2,
    @EndDate DATETIME2
)
RETURNS @MonthIds TABLE
(
    MonthId INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT
        @StartDate AS data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, data)
        FROM CTE
        WHERE data <= DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @EndDate)
    )
    INSERT INTO @MonthIds
    SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, data)
    FROM CTE

    RETURN
END
```

It takes two dates and simply generates month numbers in between the dates. I did the following configuration in DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.Entity<Activity>();
        builder.Entity(typeof(MonthIds)).HasNoKey();
        builder.HasDbFunction(() => GenerateActiveMonthsRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now));
}
public IQueryable<MonthIds> GenerateActiveMonthsRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        => FromExpression(() => GenerateActiveMonthsRange(startDate, endDate));
```

So, if I do this query in C#, it **works**.

```
var result1 = from MonthIds in context.GenerateActiveMonthsRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1))
                select MonthIds.MonthId;
```

But on this request, it throws an exception:

```
var result2 = from Activities in context.Activities
              from MonthIds in context.GenerateActiveMonthsRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1))
              select MonthIds.MonthId;

Exception:
The LINQ expression 'Activities => __context_0.GenerateActiveMonthsRange(startDate: DateTime.Now, endDate: DateTime.Now.AddYears(1))' could not be translated. 
    Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation 
        explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: Try using variables for the date values.

Comment: @ErikEJ It works, but further, I need Activities.StartDate and Activities.EndDate to be used as arguments. What can be the problem here?